# FirebaseInstanceId/FirebaseInstanceId.h not found in Flutter iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

In Flutter Project when I run pod install & pod update in Terminal it gives me below warning:

> [!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `FirebaseInstanceID (4.2.7)`
>
> Installing FirebaseInstanceID 4.2.7 (source changed to `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` from `trunk`)

and after it's done when I run Flutter project from Xcode it's giving me error as shown in screenshot.

[image: FirebaseInstanceId/FirebaseInstanceId.h not found]

> FirebaseInstanceId/FirebaseInstanceId.h not found

I am using Xcode 11.2.1 with Mac OS 10.15.1 ( Catalina )
and firebase plugin's version in Flutter project

```
firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
firebase_core: ^0.4.0
firebase_messaging: ^5.1.6
```

Previously it was working fine before macOS update.
I am trying run project since last 2 days.